# Composer install not creating autoload files

Tags: php, composer-php

In windows Git bash shell, I've done `composer install --dev` but it fails with:

```
ZipArchive::extractTo(vendor/composer/2c4b3baf/EHER-phpunit-all-in-one-fa8cfdd\src\phpunit-mock-objects\Tests\MockObject/class_implementing_inter
face_dont_call_parent_constructor.phpt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Also autoload.php is nowhere to be seen. Usually it should be at the root of vendor folder...

Is there a known issue with Composer on Windows or is there workaround for this problem?

```
"require-dev": {
        "codeception/codeception": "*",
        "codeception/aspect-mock": "*"
    },
```

Comment: No issues with Composer on Windows that I know of or have ever run into. What package are you trying to work with?  I'll see if I can get it working here.

Comment: @AndrewAngell I've updated my question. These are only two that I'm trying to install.

Comment: Seems to have installed just fine for me, so I'm afraid I probably won't be much help as that's not something I've ever run into.  I'm assuming you've done plenty of Googling already..??

Comment: @AndrewAngell yeah pretty much googled and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738983/unable-to-include-vendor-autoload-php-after-installing-composer-on-ubuntu According to this, it appears to be a bug

Comment: So did you install Composer manually or using the installer?  I'm pretty sure I used the installer and I do not have this problem.  Looks like the person in the other thread did manual.  I'm guessing there's a step that was missed when doing it that way.

Comment: what is your `composer --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
composer install --prefer-source
```